# How to split a Word cell into rows marked by carriage return?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How to split a Word cell that contains paragraphs into rows using vba?

Comment: Have you tried the `Split` function? You should be able to specify the split string, in your case it would be a line feed and/or carriage return ( `chr$(10) and/or chr$(13)`)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function

Comment: Split is to get an array of the string. I need to convert the paragraphs to rows in the Word table.
You might mean this split: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.cells.split
but unlike Excel this split doesn't split based on a marker.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by "freeflow" I recorded this macro in Word. But, I did it outside a table, then used it inside the indented cell and it worked.

```
Selection.ConvertToTable _
     Separator:=wdSeparateByParagraphs, NumColumns:=1, _
     NumRows:=15, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
With Selection.Tables(1)
    .Style = "Table Grid"
    .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
    .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
    .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
    .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
End With
```